# What are Gold Laurels rewards?

Tags: hades

I don't really get what the boon Dark Foresight does. The description:  Each rank gives you +2% greater chance for Gold Laurel rewards (Boons, Hammers, and Poms).

But I can't see what is the Gold Laurel rewards they are talking about.

So what are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different types of rewards for each room, and the laurel around the orb showing the reward for that room has a different color for some.

[From the Hades Wiki](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Chambers_and_Encounters):

> Chamber rewards are denoted on their entrance door by a symbol
> surrounded by either blue or gold laurels. Blue Laurels accompany
> persistent resources such as Keys, Darkness, or Nectar, that can be
> used to unlock new weapons, power up the Mirror of Night, or earn
> Keepsakes. Gold Laurels represent rewards that impact the current run,
> such as Obols, Boons, Centaur Hearts.

Essentially there are two pools of rewards, the blue laurel ones with resources like keys, darkness and nectar, and the gold laurel ones with god boons, hammers, etc.

This talent gives you a higher chance to get rooms with boons or poms instead of keys or darkness. The effect on hammers is probably negligible as those are limited to two per run anyway.

Comment: Also just to add, when you get the ability to 'reroll' a room reward, the reward can only be from the same tier.  You can't re-roll a blue laurel into a gold laurel, for example.

Comment: Ah was wondering why when I rolled and rolled again I seemed to always stay in the same 3. Makes sense.